# How to add class for only the selected link in C# code behind?

Tags: c#, html, css

I have a class called "is-active" and it has a colored arrow that sticks out from the nav into the main content based on which link the user clicked. The code runs a `foreach` and pulls all the categories from the database. How do I get the "is-active" class to display only for the current link? I know it works since I put it in the `openList` control and it displayed on all five categories, I just don't know how to get it to display on only the selected category.

I tried attaching jQuery to do it but adding the `linkbutton` is done all in the code behind so I am not sure how to attach the two.  Is this the only way or is there another way?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Below is my code for the categories and link button:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    LiteralControl openingDiv = new LiteralControl("<div id='MainPanel'>");
    LiteralControl closingDiv = new LiteralControl("</div>");   

    this.Controls.Add(openingDiv);

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        LiteralControl openList = new LiteralControl("<li class='" + dr["CategoryColor"].ToString() + "'>");
        LiteralControl closeList = new LiteralControl("</li>");                

        Label lblNumber = new Label();

        LinkButton myLinkButton = new LinkButton();

        myLinkButton.Text = "<span class='number'>" + dr["CategoryNumber"] + "</span>"+ dr["CategoryName"].ToString();
        myLinkButton.CommandArgument = dr["Category_ID"].ToString();
        myLinkButton.Click += myLinkButton_Click;

        this.Controls.Add(openList);
        this.Controls.Add(myLinkButton);
        this.Controls.Add(closeList);
    }
    this.Controls.Add(closingDiv);
}
void myLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
    Session["CategoryID"] = btn.CommandArgument;

    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);  
}
```

Comment: how do you define "current link"?

Comment: I am sorry if I am not understanding your question, but the link buttons are generated programmatically. When the user clicks on one of the nav linkbuttons, it updates an update panel to reflect the content of that selection.  My issue is that there is a little arrow image that should extend out from the link button when one of the five link buttons is clicked so the user can see that that is the active link.

Comment: Okay, you could add the class while updating panel (or) you could use [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) to handle the event in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its tricky because your response.redirecting in the button click handler which recreates the pages viewstate.
This means that your page will always appear as fresh and the fact a user has clicked that link has been lost.

as a workaround you could place the link id in a session variable before you response.redirect and then recall it when the page reloads.
then when in your loop, if the session variable matches the current button instance.id you set cssclass equal to is-active.

remember to clear the session variable too after you set the cssclass to is-active to avoid confusion in other pages.

also, you will have to do the id comparison after you add the button to the control tree, because this is where the system automatically generates the id for you. I can give you a full example if you wish.

keep in mind that this is a workaround and a different approach would be best.
by this I mean that if you were to use an  ispostback wrapper instead of a redirect, then on postback you could set the id to isactive much easier.

Page lifecycle is an important thing to get your head around in .net if you wish to be more proficient, especially as you mention that your using ajax update panels.
Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(VS.100).aspx it's a lot of information to take in, so bookmark it for later too as you will use it a lot.

Comment: The links are on the masterpage, but they affect the content inside of an `UpdatePanel` control.  Does this change anything you mentioned?  If so I can post additional code.  Thank you.

Comment: The above will still work in an update panel with links in the master page yes. (because your not using proper ajax partial postback functionality - because of the response.redirect()).

If you were using the suggested isPostback wrapper, then you would call panel.update() in your isPostback wrapper, but because your just redirecting, no need to do anything else.

Comment: You're doing `Response.Redirect` inside of an UpdatePanel? How does this even work?

Comment: Aaron, I would appreciate the full example you talked about if you would not mind.  I greatly appreciate your help.  It seems a simple task to do but there is so much going on.  Thank you!

Comment: Aaron, I got it solved thanks to your lead, much appreciated!

Comment: Nice, I was just preparing to reply.